# ¿ Como agregar datos a un arreglo en un servicio en angular?

Tags: angular, angular9

Tengo un servicio el cual instancia un arreglo de string global, que necesito consumir desde diferentes componentes:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DdlGlobalService {
    ddlEstadoResultante: string[] = [];
    ddlTareaOrigen: string[] = [];
    ddlAgendamientoOrigen: string[] = [];
    ddlTareaResultante: string[] = [];
}
```

Este servicio lo invoco en el método *app-datos* por inyección de dependecias

```
constructor(private ddlGlobalConfig: DdlGlobalService) { }
```

y le ingreso datos desde un método de dicho componente

```
 this.ddlGlobalConfig.ddlEstadoResultante.push(`${data.CodigoId} - ${data.DescripcionId}`);
```

El inconveniente surge en que cuando ingreso al componente  se cargan únicamente los valores que ingrese anteriormente cuando se carga el componente, gracias al constructor; pero si ingreso un nuevo valor y vuelvo a ingresar al componente no se muestra el nuevo valor.
los componentes se agregan en una misma vista

```
<div>
 <app-datos></app-datos>
 <app-revision></app-revision>
</div>
```

Trate de implementar el metodo ngOnChanges y tampoco me refresca el array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes modificar una propiedad privada en un servicio. Es necesario que las hagas publicas para que funcionen de esta manera:

```
  public ddlEstadoResultante: string[] = [];
  public ddlTareaOrigen: string[] = [];
  public ddlAgendamientoOrigen: string[] = [];
  public ddlTareaResultante: string[] = [];
```

Te dejo un ejemplo [fucional aqui](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lp2wrq)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta,pero el problema no es que no se pueda modificar los valores, porque eso lo llego hacer; la duda que tengo es que yo en componente `<app-datos>` tengo un formulario que agrega datos al array, pero en `app-revision` no se muestran los datos, estos dos componentes los cargo en dos solapas diferentes del mismo modulo, y en `<app-revision>` solo se llegan a ver los datos que ingrese en el arreglo antes de abrir la solapa, porque una vez la abro, el constructor ya se carga y no me actualiza más datos del arreglo.

Comment: Revisa el ejemplo funcional. Agrega datos al arreglo del servicio directamente y estos se aplican sin problemas reflejándose de manera inmediata en el componente servicios. Puede que tu problema este en no agregar los datos directamente al arreglo del servicio.

Comment: Haz un fork del ejemplo que te comparto replicando tu problema. Asi sera mas facil entenderte.

Comment: Ya agregue un Fork, con un botón que simula el agregado de un nuevo item en el array

Comment: Hola, no veo el fork. Pudiste resolver el problema? Veo que aceptaste la respuesta.

Comment: si, lo llegue a resolver basándome en tu ejemplo, gracias.